# If $f$ is a characteristic function, then $\int^{\infty}_0 f(ut)e^{-u}du$ is a characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

> If $f$ characteristic function, then $\,\,\,\int^{\infty}_0 f(ut)e^{-u}du\,\,$ is a characteristic function.

**My progress in the solution is:**
$$\int^{\infty}_0 f(ut)e^{-u}du= \int_{0}^{\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{itux}d\mu_{x})e^{-u}du=(fubini)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{itux-u}du)d\mu_{x}$$
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{itux-u}du)d\mu_{x}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\lim_{U\to\infty}\int_{0}^{U}e^{u(itx-1)}du)d\mu_{x}$$
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\lim_{U\to\infty}\frac{e^{Uitx}e^{-U}-1}{itx-1})d\mu_{x}, \,\,\,but \,\,(|e{^{Uitx}|\le 1;e^{-U}\to0}\,\, whit\,\,U\to\infty)$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-itx}d\mu_{x}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$$

my problem is to express the integral last, as a characteristic function.

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Suggestion: Trackback out of the deadend you are stuck in and note that $$\int^{\infty}_0 f(ut)e^{-u}du=\iint e^{it(ux)}d\nu(u,x)$$ for some probability measure on $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$ I will let you write down, hence $$\int^{\infty}_0 f(ut)e^{-u}du=E(e^{itY})$$ for $Y=UX$, where $(U,X)$ has distribution $\nu$, hence the integral on the LHS is indeed a characteristic function.